# Hibernate c3p0 connection pool initialize twice

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm trying to setup c3p0 connection pool for hibernate for the website.
Running select number of connections in the MS SQL database I see double amount of connections specified in min_size property. Having looked at logs I've found that the connection pool is seemed to be initialized twice. Does anyone know why it can be happening?

Logs:

```
[INFO] c3p0.C3P0Registry Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; 
debug? true; trace: 10]
[INFO] impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource Initializing c3p0 pool... 
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@bb009603 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> 
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@6dd5f639 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, 
acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, .......
```

After a few lines here we have again:

```
[INFO] impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource Initializing c3p0 pool... 
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@fbb6bb58 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> 
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.Wrap......
```

My Hibernate properties (partial):

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.67:1433/SSS2;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">DEV</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>

<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">6</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>


<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>

<mapping class="***.entities.User" />
<mapping class="***.entities.UserRole" />
<mapping class="***.entities.AccountType" />
```

Maven POM (partial):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-c3p0-version}</version>
</dependency>

-------
<tapestry-release-version>5.3.3</tapestry-release-version>
<hibernate-c3p0-version>3.6.0.Final</hibernate-c3p0-version>
```

I create hibernate sessions using session factory every transaction and close it in finally block of try-catch statement. (HibernateFactory just build factory if needed and opens session)

```
protected <T> List <T> findAll(Class<T> clazz) {
    List <T> objects = null;
    Session session = HibernateFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {   
        Query query = session.createQuery("from "+clazz.getName()+" as user left join fetch user.userRole");            
        objects = query.list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        handleException(e, tx);
    } finally {
        HibernateFactory.close(session);
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Related links:

1. https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=937286&sid=42b4645f9e9e037d876194e15f9b2f77
2. https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=941919

Answer (score 0):

I think that "hbm2ddl.auto" parameter is forcing double initialization... 
Try to remove validate from hibernate cfg file and tapestry should initialize session only once